# How to manually clear the tf.function caches (or manage the max size) in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The example below shows a simple way of clearing the caches manually. Is there a more standard/stable way of managing the cache going forward? Or perhaps a pattern to avoid this in the first place?

We have some case where the batch-size varies a lot and we hit memory issues as I the def_fun is not going out of scope and the cache is likely not clearing.

```
In [164]: @tf.function
     ...: def f(x):
     ...:     return dict(something=x ** 2)
     ...:
     ...:
     ...:

In [165]: f._list_all_concrete_functions_for_serialization()
Out[165]: []

In [166]: _ = f(tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randn(109, 3).astype(np.float32)))

In [167]: _ = f(tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randn(111, 3).astype(np.float32)))

In [168]: f._list_all_concrete_functions_for_serialization()
Out[168]:
[<tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac73e0d358>,
 <tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac71d41a58>]

In [169]: f._stateful_fn._function_cache._garbage_collectors
Out[169]:
[<tensorflow.python.eager.function._FunctionGarbageCollector at 0x7fac94252390>,
 <tensorflow.python.eager.function._FunctionGarbageCollector at 0x7fac7b0c6048>,
 <tensorflow.python.eager.function._FunctionGarbageCollector at 0x7fac7b0c6d68>]

In [170]: f._stateful_fn._function_cache._garbage_collectors[0]
Out[170]: <tensorflow.python.eager.function._FunctionGarbageCollector at 0x7fac94252390>

In [171]: f._stateful_fn._function_cache._garbage_collectors[0]._cache
Out[171]:
OrderedDict([(CacheKey(input_signature=('UTd1s109-3-u', None), parent_graph=None, device_functions=(), colocation_stack=(), in_cross_replica_context=False),
              <tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac7371def0>),
             (CacheKey(input_signature=('UTd1s111-3-u', None), parent_graph=None, device_functions=(), colocation_stack=(), in_cross_replica_context=False),
              <tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac77a514a8>),
             (CacheKey(input_signature=('URu', (TensorSpec(shape=(111, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='x'),)), parent_graph=None, device_functions=(), colocation_stack=(), in_cross_replica_context=False),
              <tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac73e0d358>),
             (CacheKey(input_signature=('URu', (TensorSpec(shape=(109, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='x'),)), parent_graph=None, device_functions=(), colocation_stack=(), in_cross_replica_context=False),
              <tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac71d41a58>)])

In [172]: f._stateful_fn._function_cache._garbage_collectors[0]._cache.popitem()
Out[172]:
(CacheKey(input_signature=('URu', (TensorSpec(shape=(109, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='x'),)), parent_graph=None, device_functions=(), colocation_stack=(), in_cross_replica_context=False),
 <tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac71d41a58>)

In [173]: f._stateful_fn._function_cache._garbage_collectors[0]._cache.popitem()
Out[173]:
(CacheKey(input_signature=('URu', (TensorSpec(shape=(111, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='x'),)), parent_graph=None, device_functions=(), colocation_stack=(), in_cross_replica_context=False),
 <tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac73e0d358>)

In [174]: f._stateful_fn._function_cache._garbage_collectors[0]._cache.popitem()
Out[174]:
(CacheKey(input_signature=('UTd1s111-3-u', None), parent_graph=None, device_functions=(), colocation_stack=(), in_cross_replica_context=False),
 <tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac77a514a8>)

In [175]: f._stateful_fn._function_cache._garbage_collectors[0]._cache.popitem()
Out[175]:
(CacheKey(input_signature=('UTd1s109-3-u', None), parent_graph=None, device_functions=(), colocation_stack=(), in_cross_replica_context=False),
 <tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction at 0x7fac7371def0>)

In [176]: f._stateful_fn._function_cache._garbage_collectors[0]._cache.popitem()
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm doing a meta-learning loop where I periodically have to re-wrap my methods in tf.function, and am hitting a memory leak. I believe it's related to the tf.function cache, but can't find a good way to clear it out.

Comment: I think I did find something but can't find it now. I basically grabbed a tf.function decorated function in the REPL and looked at the underscore methods like f._get_tracing_count and then read the code. I think there was somethign to pop there.

Answer (score -1):

before calling tf.function, copy the object.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import copy

@tf.function
def test1(a):
    print('trace')
    return a * a

test2 = copy.copy(test1)
print(test1(1))
print(test1.experimental_get_tracing_count())

print(test1(1))
print(test1.experimental_get_tracing_count())

print(test2(1))
print(test2.experimental_get_tracing_count())
```

result:

```
trace
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
1
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
1
trace
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
1
```